# MVVM Light - Silverlight 4 Source Code

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

Originally asked on mvvmlight.codeplex.com...

Will the source code for the Silverlight 4 version of MVVM light be posted anytime soon? The binaries work but using the published source code does not. In particular, the EventToCommand functionality is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The only person that can answer that is Laurent Bugnion. His contact info is below:
http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/lbugnion